# How can limit how many times an operator shows up in my maths quiz in vb?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, computer-science

My task was to create a 10 question maths quiz with 2 random numbers and a random operator (only +, - or *) for each question. Also the program must ask for the users name. Which I have done.

But as my quiz has only 10 questions, there is a very small probability that one of the operators will be in the majority or that one may not show up. So basically I need something that can limit how many times each operator shows up, for example each operator can only show up 4 times.

As you can see from my code, I'm coding in form. I would be very grateful if you could help me with this as I couldn't find anything on the internet for it and I'm also not too sure how to go about solving this problem either.

```
Private Sub StartTheQuiz()
    number1 = randomizer.Next(1, 13)
    number2 = randomizer.Next(1, number1)
    leftpluslbl.Text = number1.ToString
    rightpluslbl.Text = number2.ToString
    userinput.Value = 0
    Correct.Visible = False
    Incorrect.Visible = False

End Sub
Public Sub TheOperator()

    Randomize()

    operation = randomizer.Next(1, 4)
    addmintime = operation
    If addmintime = 1 Then
        answer = number1 + number2
        operatorlbl.Text = "+"
        Userinput.Value = useranswer
    ElseIf addmintime = 2 Then
        answer = number1 - number2
        operatorlbl.Text = "-"
        Userinput.Value = useranswer
    ElseIf addmintime = 3 Then
        answer = number1 * number2
        operatorlbl.Text = "x"
        Userinput.Value = useranswer
    End If

End Sub
Public Function CheckTheAnswer()
    If userinput.Value = answer Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start.Click
    If NameBox.Text = "What is your name? Enter your name here" Then
        NameBox.BackColor = Color.Red
        NextBtn.Visible = False
        Check.Visible = False
    Else
        StartTheQuiz()
        NameBox.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
        Start.Enabled = False
        Start.Visible = False
        TheOperator()
        question = 0
        score = 0
        Check.Visible = True
        NameBox.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Check_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Check.Click

    If CheckTheAnswer() = True Then
        Correct.Visible = True
        Incorrect.Visible = False
        question = question + 1
        score = score + 1
    ElseIf CheckTheAnswer() = False Then
        Correct.Visible = False
        Incorrect.Visible = True
        question = question + 1
        score = score + 0
    End If
    NextBtn.Visible = True
    Check.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub NextBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextBtn.Click


    If question < 10 Then
        StartTheQuiz()
        TheOperator()
        Check.Visible = True
        NextBtn.Visible = False
    ElseIf question >= 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You have scored " & score & "/10")
        MessageBox.Show("Goodbye")
        Me.Close()

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Can't you store in a variable a counter for each operation and when the limit is reached the operation is blocked ... You could random a new number if the operation is marked as blocked !

Comment: "My task was to create a quiz with a random operator" "there is a small probability that one of the operators will be in the majority or that one may not show up" -- Yes; that sounds like you've met the specification, why do you want to change it?

Comment: Because all 3 of my operators need to show up somewhat equally in my quiz @TessellatingHeckler

Comment: On a side note, `Randomize()` does absolutely nothing in your code as it pairs with the legacy `Rnd()` function and you're using the newer `Random()` class.

Comment: A different approach would be to build a **list** of operators with the correct ratios you want, and then **shuffle** that list.  Then you'd simply extract the operators from your shuffled list as you go...

Comment: Expanding @Idle_Mind's to keep the numbers balanced, you could also set each operator to appear 3 times, then randomly select one to appear 4 times, then shuffle the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what I mentioned in the comments.  It builds a list of the desired number of operations in equal quantities, then shows how to pull a random one from that list:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Operations As New List(Of String)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Operations = CreateOperations(10)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If Operations.Count > 0 Then
            Dim operation As String = NextRandomOperation()
            Debug.Print(operation)
        Else
            Debug.Print("No more operations in list!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function CreateOperations(ByVal NumberOperations As Integer) As List(Of String)
        Dim operators() As String = {"+", "-", "X"}
        Dim operations As New List(Of String)
        While Operations.Count < NumberOperations
            Operations.AddRange(operators)
        End While
        While Operations.Count > NumberOperations
            Operations.RemoveAt(Operations.Count - 1)
        End While
        Return operations
    End Function

    Private Function NextRandomOperation() As String
        Static R As New Random
        If Operations.Count > 0 Then
            Dim index As Integer = R.Next(Operations.Count)
            Dim operation As String = Operations(index)
            Operations.RemoveAt(index)
            Return operation
        End If
        Return ""
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I shall use that.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution above will always produce four +, three - and three X. If you want a more random distribution you need to randomize the operators() array.

```
    Dim rnd As New System.Random
    Dim operators() As String = New String() {"+", "-", "X"}.OrderBy(Function() rnd.Next).ToArray
```